# How to change button's color?

Tags: java, swing, awt

In my program I've got 2 buttons: the first one changes frame background, the second one changes button background(only for itself). The point is that program should change button background for every button in the program(not only for itself). How am I supposed to to rewrite *dialog*?

```
class ButtonBackgroundChange implements ActionListener{
    private JDialog dialog;
    private JColorChooser chooser;
    private Color currentBackground;

    public ButtonBackgroundChange(JButton button1, Component component, Color currentBackground){
        this.currentBackground = currentBackground;
        chooser = new JColorChooser();
        dialog = JColorChooser.createDialog(component, "Background Color", false /* not modal */, chooser, event -> button1.setBackground(chooser.getColor()), null /* no Cancel button listener */);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        chooser.setColor(currentBackground);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you store your buttons in a list that you pass in to the function you will be able to iterate through it and set the background color for each button.

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic Can I do it without a list? With using EventQueue, for instance?

Comment: If you want to _change button background for every button in the program_ you need to reference each and every button. The best is to store the references in a Collection as proposed by @MarkoMarinkovic or alternatively list all of them in the code.

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic I've added a list, thanks for the comment

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your buttons in a list that you pass in to the function you will be able to iterate through it and set the background color for each button.